# Schedule Cell Override Background Color not showing in sheet

Tags: revit-api

```
headingStyle.BackgroundColor = new ColorPreset()[ColorPresets.Cream];
headingStyle.SetCellStyleOverrideOptions(new TableCellStyleOverrideOptions() { BackgroundColor = true });
```

I am applying an override to add a background colour.  I am setting the cell style:

TableSectionData.SetCellStyle

TableSectionData.RefreshData

I have tried refreshing the data but when an instance is placed on a sheet, the overrides don't show but it is of course showing in the schedule itself.  Is there a step I'm missing to make the sheet background colour match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested lots of workarounds, you can't set the TableCellStyle.SheetBackgroundColor, and it doesn't change with the BackgroundColor.

The only way to override the cell color is to copy the TableCellStyle from an existing cell/field.

An easy example is to create a dummy schedule, color the headers manually in Revit, by API, get their TableCellStyle and set the required field style to it.

Comment: I have found that it works with SectionType.Header but not SectionType.Body indicating that they are handled differently.  Could the header style be modified and then copied into the body to set the missing properties/behaviour?

Comment: I guess you can override:
- SectionType.Header which include the Schedule Name. 
- The whole column, by getting the ScheduleField then SetStyle. 
- A column header by SectionType.Body then SetCellStyle(0, [Column index], AvailableStyle). 

I remember I did succeed setting a certain body cell, but for some reason, I can't get it to work right now.

Answer (score 0):

I am now passing a schedule into my method to get its **TableCellStyle** and **TableCellStyleOverrideOptions** to update target cells as suggested by Mahmoud AbdElMoneam.

Seems that **TableCellStyle.SheetBackgroundColor** should either have a Set or the API should set it privately when **TableCellStyle.BackgroundColor** is set in the API.  Not as clean as I would like.

Comment: @Billa do you have any suggestions or example I can follow? I'm not sure how I should improve it.